# LNK2019: unresolved external symbol in C++

Tags: c++, function, linker, header-files

It's another of those questions... but I can't understand for the life of me, what is wrong.

**Function.h**

```
void doStuff(unsigned char a, unsigned char b, unsigned char c);
```

**Function.cpp**

```
#include "Function.h"

void doStuff(unsigned char a, unsigned char b, unsigned char c)
{
    char array[3] = {a, b ,c};
}
```

**Implement.cpp**

```
    #include "Function.h"

    class OSKeyInjector_Win32 : public OSKeyInjector
    {
    public :
        OSKeyInjector_Win32() {
        }

        virtual ~OSKeyInjector_Win32() {
        }

        virtual bool injectKeyEvents( const std::vector<KeyEventDesc> & intputlist)
        {
          do
            {
              doStuff(144, 90, 100);
            }while(0);

          return true;

       }
   };
```

*unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl doStuff(unsigned char,unsigned char,unsigned char)" (?doStuff@@YAXEEE@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall OSKeyInjector_Win32::injectKeyEvents(class std::vector > const &)" (?injectKeyEvents@OSKeyInjector_Win32@@UAE_NABV?$vector@UKeyEventDesc@@V?$allocator@UKeyEventDesc@@@std@@@std@@@Z)*

Comment: Is `Function.cpp` actually linked to your final artifact (executable, shared library)?

Comment: I thought it would do it automatically since the folder is included in additional directories and auto-completion worked.. but it didn't. Adding manually through Solution Explorer fixed the issue.